# Show that the sum of mean-zero random variables is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

### Summarize the problem

On a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$, I am considering a sequence $(X_{n})_{n \ge 1}$ of real-valued, independent and identically distributed random variables, taking each of the three values 1, -1, 0 with probability 1/3.

Define the summation for $N \geq 1$

$$ S_{N} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} X_{n}$$

I define "*bounded*" as shown by Ramon van Handel in his book "*Stochastic Calculus, Filtering, and Stochastic Control*", which is as follows:

> A random variable is called *bounded* if there exists $K \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $|X| \leq K$ almost surely.

I want to show that $S_N$ is unbounded as $N \rightarrow \infty $

### Describe what you've tried

This seems to boil down to showing that $S_N \notin \mathcal{L}^{1}$ almost surely.

If one considers a contradiction argument, suggesting that for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$ a real-valued $K_{n}'$ exists where $$K_n' = n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1$$

We have by definition of $S_n$ that $|S_n| \leq K_n'$  $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

We also have that no $\delta>0$ such that $$K_n'' = K_n' - \delta_n < K_n'$$ exists where $K_n''$ is a bound of $S_n$ for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$.

However if we take the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty $ we can see that

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} K_n' = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \notin \mathcal{L^1}$$

### What I would like help with

In this stack exchange answer by 
Davide Giraudo

> (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9849/davide-giraudo), Does the Strong Law of Large Numbers imply the following?, URL (version: 2015-01-28): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1124001

He utilises the strong law of large numbers, in particular a result showing that $S_n$ and $n \Bbb{E}(X) \rightarrow \infty$ converge to the same limit. But this does not apply here since the expected value of X is zero.

The statement seems quite intuitive, however I believe that the solution should be more complicated, in particular I have not considered the fact that $X$ is a random variable of finite variation.

It's quite possible I've gone down the wrong path so any help would be great.

Comment: Try finding the probability that $S_n > \sqrt{n}$. If you can show that this is bounded away from $0$ for any $n$, then you are done. Also you might want to look up about Law of iterated logarithm. It is related to the problem you are trying to solve.